# How to update Galaxy S4 to Lollipop or Latest Android version?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 6.0-marshmallow, 4.3-jelly-bean

How to update this Galaxy Not rooted S4 GT- I9505 from Android 4.3 to Android 5.0 or 6.0?
Currently not getting or not showing any updates either in this device or from Samsung Smart Switch/Samsung Kies.

[image]

[image]

Additionally, Not showing latest android version in SamMobile website ([Firmware for GT-I9505](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I9505/BTU/)) against the above device specifications. Currently it is still showing Android version as **4.3**  `Now how can we update it to Lollipop version?`

[image]

Comment: My query is not duplicate. Please note that we struggled to get update the current jellybean version to kitkat itself. `Still the phone is using in Jellybean without any update to kitkat or any other new released supported android versions for S4 GT-I9505 model.`

Comment: Samsung UK or India customer care has confirmed us to wait till the phone receive any updates and no other alternate way unless Smart Switch or Kies display any updates. So far I've not seen any updates with the both softwares. Till date no updates are received with the model GT - I9505

Answer (score 3):

You can easily update your Galaxy S4 to Android 5.0.1 Lollipop without root. As you have shared the screenshots, it shows your device is up-to-date but your region might have not received the latest update yet.

But you can check the sammobile firmware page [over here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I9505/).

It clearly shows that Lollipop 5.0.1 has been released for those regions, Now If your region is listed over there or not. You can simply download the firmware and flash it using Odin3. (If you don't know how to update using Odin, I've written a step-by-step guide [on my blog](http://www.progeeksblog.com/download-odin3-for-windows-jodin3-for-mac-os-x-and-linux/)).

I hope that the above instructions helps you to update to Android Lollipop. Now You also have said about Android Marshmallow, Now officially it is not available for your phone model and I am pretty sure it won't be in the near future as Samsung does not support their models too long and Galaxy S4 is now quite old.

But doesn't mean you can't have Android Marshmallow on your phone. In order to have it, you need to root your phone and install Custom ROM such CyanogenMod 13.

Let me know if you want to know more in details and I hope you've found my answer useful.

Comment: I updated the question. As we couldn't find the released Lollipop version against above phone version and specifications in sammobile firmware site. Kindly help!

Comment: At @Imran: Can we discuss this concern over Chat room

Comment: Why not sure, just let me know.

Comment: Invite me to chat room.