# Download AT&T OTA update while out of country

Tags: samsung, ota-update, att

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 that I want to install Android 5.1 on.  AT&T released this as an OTA last year (https://www.att.com/devicehowto/tutorial.html#!/stepbystep/id/stepbystep_KM1143907?make=Samsung&model=GalaxyS4I337), but I whenever I check for updates it says nothing is available.  The phone is currently running Android 4.4.

Could this be because I'm currently living abroad and accessing the internet via local Wi-Fi?  Is there another way to get the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be connected to the AT&T network to receive the update, which isn't possible if you're abroad.

If you can't get the update through auto updates on your phone, or via Kies, then you can download the firmware and use Odin to flash it.

I found [this answer helpful](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144924), as well as [this tutorial](http://www.android.gs/update-att-galaxy-s4-android-5-0-1-ucugoc3-lollipop-os/) that shows you step by step how to do it.